# Create Webapp2 auth user with date property

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, date, webapp2

I have this basic model:

```
class User(auth_models.User):
username = ndb.StringProperty()
email = ndb.StringProperty()
first_name = ndb.StringProperty()
last_name = ndb.StringProperty()
employee_start_date = ndb.DateProperty()
```

However, when I create the user:

```
success, obj = self.auth.store.user_model.create_user(
    "auth:"+ username,
    unique_properties = ['email'],
    email = emailaddress,
    first_name = firstname,
    last_name = lastname,
    employee_start_date = startdate)
```

I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Property employee_start_date does not support <type 'datetime.date'> types.
```

*(Note: creating the user is successful if I don't include the employee_start_date)*

Now, from what I can tell by searching the internet, this is because the user_model is an expando model, and for some reason it doesn't support date fields. However, I don't know that for sure.

I also tried adding it immediately after creating the user, but I get the same error message with this:

```
obj.employee_start_date = startdate
obj.put()
```

Is there a way to add a date property to this user model?

Answer (score 0):

The `startdate` value that you try to assign to `employee_start_date` is not of type `date`, but `datetime`. In order for your code to work, you have two options:

1) Change `employee_start_date` to `datetime`:

```
employee_start_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

2) Make `startdate` variable as `date` and not `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

to use your own User class, make sure to set

```
config = {'webapp2_extras.auth':{
    'user_model': 'your_auth.User'
}}
```

for the webapp2.WSGIApplication config argument